# How to make Epiphany (Gnome-Web) ask where to save a file

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, epiphany

Epiphany saves files without asking. Is there a way to change its settings to make it ask where to save a specific file before actually saving it?

Comment: This is on Xubuntu 18.04, correct?

Comment: @DKBose Correct!

Comment: "GNOME" software usually comes with reduced options compared to other software. If this feature is important to you, stay with a mainstream browser such as Firefox which does allow you flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be impossible, even through `dconf-editor` or `gsettings`.

Comment: So how do i make it ask where to save the file?

Comment: OP seems to want the browser to "ask where to save each time", not to change the default save location. AFAICT, there's no such option.

Comment: @N0rbert I see. Please delete the answer, as it is just misleading now. P.S. The icon is on top right, at least for me.

Comment: Walked through `dconf-editor`, can't found corresponding keys in `org.gnome.epiphany` schemas, so it is impossible.